# Angular 2 RC5 with router 3.0.0.rc.1 problems with http get

Tags: angular

I am trying to upgrade our huge app from angular RC4 to RC5 with router 3.0.0.rc.1. I made the necessary changes with app.module, main.ts, routes and moved all directive, pipes and providers to app.module. Also added empty body (body: '') to all the http.get(). But now I'm facing an issue where the http.get() is not getting called from authService. And this get call is required because this is where I'm trying to get access token and refresh token.

For some reason , this is happening only from authService. Every other http.get() gets called.

Below is my function to call http.get()

```
  public getToken<T>(){
  var token = this.cookie.get('token');
  let self = this;
  this.http.get<T>('api/gettoken/TO'
    .replace(/TO/g, token.token)).subscribe((refreshtok)=>{
         //Some additional code
    }
  });
}
```

So it doesnt get into http.get()

Did I miss some step in the migration to RC5 that's causing this issue?

AuthService is not calling any functions from httpService. What connection between the 2 services am I messing up?

Answer (score 0):

The Http Get function does not take a `<T>` type. Also I would recommend using Typescript's template string feature over that replace().

```
this.http.get(`api/gettoken/${token.token}`)
```

Note those are backticks not single quotes

Comment: "The Http Get function does not take a <T> type"  - is this from RC5 onwards? Because In RC4, this worked perfectly fine. 
Also after further testing , I noticed that AuthService isnt going into httpService at all even though i am importing httpService in AuthService. According to RC5 steps, I have imported both the services into app.module and added them to the providers[]. Am i messing up some link between the 2 services?

Comment: You are also adding Http to your service constructor, right? Also if possible for your project you might want to upgrade Angular2 all the way to the final release which is now out (instead of just the RC5).

Comment: Yes Http is in the AuthService constructor. I will try to upgrade to final release and check. Thanks